# A where clause that uses nested attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following association in my Case model:

```
belongs_to :title,
    -> { where lang: I18n.locale },
    class_name: "Translation",
    foreign_key: 'title_tid',
    primary_key: 'id'
has_many :titles,
    class_name: "Translation",
    foreign_key: 'id',
    primary_key: 'title_tid'

belongs_to :desc,
    -> { where lang: I18n.locale },
    class_name: "Translation",
    foreign_key: 'desc_tid',
    primary_key: 'id'
has_many :descriptions,
    class_name: "Translation",
    foreign_key: 'id',
    primary_key: 'desc_tid'
```

So to get the title I would do:

```
my_case.title.text
```

I need to find a specific case with a specific title:

```
Case.where(title.text: case_title)
```

But this does not work. Is there a way to do a where with a nested attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're going to need to [join](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#hash-conditions) to that table.  The attribute isn't nested; it's part of a [`belongs_to`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-belongs-to-association) relationship.

```
Case.joins(:title).where(translations: {text: case_title})
```